# session variable loses value after detailsview new cancel event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have 3 controls on my web page, a dropdownlist, a detailsview, and a listview.

the dropdownlist controls the record to be displayed on the detailsview and the listview.

when the detailsview enters "new" mode I clear the items of the detailsview and clear the values of the dropdownlist:

```
 If e.CommandName = "New" Then
        lvRecipeSteps.Items.Clear()
        ddRecipeItemNumber.Items.Clear()
    End If
```

this shows the page with no items on the dropdownlist, the detailsview and listview on new/insert mode.

the issue happens when I click the cancel event, then this code is executed

```
If e.CommandName = "Cancel" Then
        ddRecipeItemNumber.DataBind()
        ddRecipeItemNumber.SelectedValue = Session("Id").ToString()

    End If
```

the session variable Id gets assign on page load

```
    Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Session("Id") = ddRecipeItemNumber.SelectedValue
```

I get an error: "not set to an instance of an object" pointing to: ddRecipeItemNumber.SelectedValue = Session("Id").ToString()

I want to be able to save the record Id, that is on the dropdown before the new/insert event begins, and then if the event gets cancelled, set the controls back to the record that were displaying before the insert/new action started.

I read that using sessions variables is a good way of doing this, but I most be doing something wrong that when the event cancel is executed, the values is then lost.

Please let me know if I can get some help finding a solution for my problem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place the `Session("Id") = ddRecipeItemNumber.SelectedValue` inside the condition below:

> ```
>           if (!IsPostBack)
>             {
>                 Session("Id") = ddRecipeItemNumber.SelectedValue;
>             }
> ```

just need to convert it to VB

**UPDATE 1**

If your code is not inside a Data control then you could allocate its selected value like the code below:

on your aspx form:

> ```
>   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
>                   OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" 
>                   AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:DropDownList>
> ```

on your code behind:

> ```
>   protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         Session["Id"] = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Value;
>     }
> ```

**UPDATE 2**

also if you want to change the selected value on your code this would be the right code to do:
instead of this line `ddRecipeItemNumber.SelectedValue = Session("Id").ToString()`

use this one

> ```
>   ddRecipeItemNumber.Items.FindByValue(Session("Id").ToString()).Selected = true;
> ```

Comment: if your ddRecipeItemNumber is inside the details view or listview you cannot set the value straight away from the Page_Load. I'll update the answer above for you to achieve that.

Comment: the ddRecipeItemNumber is outside detailsview

Comment: I just got home. Will try your code to the best of my skills. Thank you

Comment: "if your ddRecipeItemNumber is inside the details view or listview you cannot set the value straight away from the Page_Load. I'll update the answer above for you to achieve that" Does that mean that I need to remove the variable from page load? Thank you.

Comment: The code above did not work. I still lose the value of the Session variable when entering Cancel event.

Comment: because you said that you don't have the drop down list inside any data control, then the above update is based on that. so just remove that line from Page_Load and use it in the selectedindexchanged method

Comment: where do i need to use this line?:   ddRecipeItemNumber.Items.FindByValue(Session("Id").ToString()).Selected = true;

And, I don't understand, I do not see the event onSelectIndexChange being triggered before this part:
 If e.CommandName = "New" Then
        lvRecipeSteps.Items.Clear()
        ddRecipeItemNumber.Items.Clear()
    End If

Comment: I do not think the on-select-index-change will give me what I need :/
If I remove the initialization of the session variable from the page load, then that variable is empty when the New event occurs, and when the Cancel event occurs (latest being the original issue).
There most be a way to be able to save the value that was previously selected on the dropdownlist whether it was changed or not, and then access it so that can be used to set the controls on the record before the New event initiated, but was cancelled.

Comment: thank you for your help so far, unfortunately is not working for me yet.